# django-filters: icontains type of lookup expression doesn't work properly

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I am using `django-filter` to filter the result query based on the user input.

Imagine that I have the following Post:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "salam",
        "content": "chetori",
        "is_draft": false,
        "author": 1
    }
]
```

I have created a filterset_class as following:

```
class PostFilter(filter.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = {
            'title': ['icontains'],
            'content': ['icontains'],
        }
```

whenever I use that icontains doesn't work properly, for example `http://localhost:8000/posts/?content=chetorz` query should returns empty list but it doesn't:

[image: query result]

But it works whenever I add the following line to project `settings.py`:

```
FILTERS_DEFAULT_LOOKUP_EXPR = 'icontains'
```

I don't know how can I change the code to work properly without changing the default behavior of the LOOKUP_EXPR.

**PS** views.py:

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    filter_backends = [rest_filters.SearchFilter, filters.DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = PostFilter
    search_fields = ['title', 'content', 'author__user__username']

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == "create":
            self.permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

        elif self.action == "list":
            pass

        return super(PostViewSet, self).get_permissions()
```

Comment: You filter with `?content__icontains=chetorz`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sorry, I don't understand what you say, isn't there another approach that works the same? I mean `content=chetors` returns None and `content=chetor` returns an array with one member

Comment: You filter with a GET request to `/posts/?content__icontains=chetorz`, so `content__icontains=...`, not `content=...`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem But whenever I add `FILTERS_DEFAULT_LOOKUP_EXPR = 'icontains'`  without `__icontains` it works well. Isn't there a way that change the behavior for just one model without changing the default?

Comment: yes, because the `FILTERS_DEFAULT_LOOKUP_EXPR` is `exact`, that is the one without a "lookup" part.

Comment: TRy ***`?content=chetor`*** (without the ***`z`***) I assume you have misunderstood the `icontains`

Comment: @ArakkalAbu: the expected behavior is to retrieve an *empty* list... The point is that the OP expects *no* results, but still retrieves items.

Comment: Can you show the view that you are using @MostafaGhadimi

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Yeah, I also have tried `contains` but it doesn't work. I will add view in 
a minute.

Comment: @MostafaGhadimi: you can override the field and specify the `lookup_expr=...` in the field to specify how to handle that field.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For your filterset, you need to append the lookup, so:

```
http://localhost:8000/posts/?content__icontains=chetorz
```

You can however work by default with an `icontains` lookup, by specifying the field manually, like:

```
class PostFilter(filter.FilterSet):
    title = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    content = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'content']
```

Comment: Is it possible to filter based on foreign key? For example the post has a foreign key to Author and Author has username field. Is it possible to filter by it?

Comment: @MostafaGhadimi: yes, why would that be impossible? If you want to filter for example on the `username` of an `author`, you can add `username = django_filters.CharField(field_name='author__username)`